# How to put values to 3d array which is dynamically allocated in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing some codes to understand how dynamically allocating 3d array works in C++.
This is just a sample code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int Na = 3;
int Nd = 3;
int Ny = 3;

int main() {

    double*** tempmax = new double** [Na];
    for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
        tempmax[i] = new double* [Nd];
        for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
            tempmax[i][j] = new double[Ny];
            fill_n(tempmax[i][j], Ny, 2);
        }
    }
    
    tempmax[2][2][1] = 3;
    
}
```

First, I allocate 'tempmax' 3d array filled with 2.
Then I was trying to change the value to 3 for tempmax[2][2][1].
Then I got this warning message "Warning    C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'tempmax':  the writable size is 'int Na*8' bytes, but '24' bytes might be written."

Some people say that sometimes this is just a false warning.
And I just want to check whether this is false or there is some basic mistake I am making here.

Comment: BTW what compiler are you using and with what compilation options?

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766). Also you are including a LOT of unnecessary headers. Also also this code is fine to figure out how things work, but if you plan on doing anything else, don't reinvent the wheel, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a false warning, but a justified one. You should have made `Na`, `Nd` and `Ny` at least `const` or better `constexpr`.

As they are, they are global variables visible and modifiable by other compilation units. For the compiler the logic goes "they might change to be smaller than 3". Const-correctness also helps with that diagnostic.

Besides, you are leaking memory. Everything you allocate with `new` you must `delete` again. Don't ever get used to omitting that.

Besides, that warning is actually in `/W4` or `/Wall`. Most of the warnings added beyond `/W3` usually hardly actually warn about real, immediate issues, but are mostly in the "things could go wrong under condition X" category.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a class, or get a library that does. What you're doing is not very optimal as you do many allocations. Also, you'll be chasing pointers around, which is also not cache friendly. Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class matrix_3d {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_data;
    std::size_t m_cx, m_cy, m_cz;

public:
    matrix_3d(std::size_t const cx,
              std::size_t const cy,
              std::size_t const cz)
        : m_data{ new T[cx * cy * cz] }
        , m_cx{ cx }
        , m_cy{ cy }
        , m_cz{ cz }
    {}

    T& get(std::size_t const x,
        std::size_t const y,
        std::size_t const z) noexcept {
        // use the const version
        return const_cast<T&>(static_cast<matrix_3d const*>(this)->get(x, y, z));
    }

    T const& get(std::size_t const x,
        std::size_t const y,
        std::size_t const z) const noexcept {
        auto const idx = (z * m_cx * m_cy) + (y * m_cx) + x;
        assert(idx < m_cx * m_cy * m_cz);
        return m_data[idx];
    }
};

int main() {
    std::size_t const cx = 4;
    std::size_t const cy = 3;
    std::size_t const cz = 2;

    matrix_3d<int> m(cx, cy, cz);

    int n = 0;
    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < cx; ++x) {
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < cy; ++y) {
            for (std::size_t z = 0; z < cz; ++z) {
                m.get(x, y, z) = (n++);
            }
        }
    }

    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < cx; ++x) {
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < cy; ++y) {
            for (std::size_t z = 0; z < cz; ++z) {
                printf("%d\n", m.get(x, y, z));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should additionally consider adding move/copy constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: @Ext3h that would completely disallow adding copy/move assignment operators.